# Powerpoint: hide picture in slide preview while keeping animation active

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I want to show a picture over my slide upon clicking, but I want to hide the picture in the preview so that I can still edit my content without having to move the image.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Literally no,  but you may have some workarounds:

1. put the image BEHIND the text and make the text disappear when you want to show your picture.
2. instead of doing the animation in the slide make 2 similar slides: with and without the picture.
   This case it'll be a bit more long to edit your presentation,  as after editing the slide without picture you'll need to duplicate text to the other one.
   Advantage of this view is that you'll slides with both visible text and picture for printout.

Comment: it's still not possible as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

Probably a better solution will be to use the Selection Pane (Home > Select > Selection Pane...). There you can easily hide and rename the objects in your slide. Hidden objects won't be animated, so when you're done editing you should make them visible again.

(It's an old topic, but I found it via Google, so maybe this can help others who have the same question.)